# Why is 1 in [2,3] true in javascript while 2 in [2,3] is false

Tags: javascript, arrays, contains

I just wondering about the behavior of the "in" clause. It should not return inclusion ? what 1 in [2,3] means ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Relational

Comment: in checks for property not value

Comment: Because it is not looking for the number one.... it is the index of one....

Answer (score 2):

`in` checks for index

index start from zero

`1 in [2,3]` means does that array have index `1` in it , which is true

basically it checks for keys in an object, in simple terms, and in array indices are the keys

Answer (score 2):

Because `in` checks for the "keys". Your array has a "key" `1`. (keys are the index in an array)

Don't use `in` to check if an element exists in an array, `in` is used for object literals instead.

Use `includes()` instead

```
console.log([2,3].includes(1));
```